# QT: timer is not working in changeEvent but it works in timerEvent

Tags: c++, qt, timer, qt4

I have this function is part of `qtdlg.cpp`.
Here is the constructor for this class:

```
qtdlg::qtdlg()
{
    timer1.start(100, this); // 100 msec updating
}

void qtdlg::changeEvent(QEvent *e)
{
    QWidget::changeEvent(e);
    switch (e->type()) {
    case QEvent::LanguageChange:
        ui.retranslateUi(this);
        break;
    case QEvent::Timer:
        {
            // do some stuff // it never comes here! 
        }
        break;
    default:
        break;
   }
}
```

I know it works if I use:

```
void TempCompStart::timerEvent(QTimerEvent *event)
{
}
```

My question is that why it does not work in the first case with changeEvent but it work with timerEvent? Is it not support to work this way!

Comment: Some people in here like to downvote with no reason!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`changeEvent` handles state changes. It is called for example when the window state is changed, title is changed or locale is changed. So it will not get called periodically like `timerEvent`.

If you want to handle timer event like that, you should reimplement the `eventFilter` like :

```
bool qtdlg::eventFilter(QObject  *obj, QEvent * event)
{

    if((qtdlg *)obj == this && event->type()==QEvent::Timer )
    {
        // do some stuff
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Don't forget to install the event filter in the constructor :

```
this->installEventFilter(this);
```

Comment: @Samer You can also just reimplement [`QObject::event`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qobject.html#event), that way you won't have to install an event filter and check the object.